# Sorting a List with OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq

Why won't the code below sort my list?

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>() { "bac", "abc", "cab" };
lst.OrderBy(p => p.Substring(0));
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

since OrderBy returns IOrderedEnumerable you should do:

```
lst = lst.OrderBy(p => p.Substring(0)).ToList();
```

you can also do the following:

```
lst.Sort();
```

Comment: Note that `List<T>.Sort` is an unstable sort, whereas OrderBy is stable. And of course in this case the ordering is *only* by first letter, whereas using `list.Sort` without any parameters will sort by the whole string.

Comment: Jon, `.Substring(0)` returns the whole string, I believe...  For the first character, needs `.Substring(0,1)` or `[0]`...

Comment: how to sort list<string> with specific search key letter order as first? I have tried this but not working  code: `lst = lst.OrderByDescending(p => p.Substring(0)[0] == searchValue[0]).ToList();`

Answer (score 23):

You are confusing LINQ operations with a method that changes the variable it is applied to (i.e. an instance method of the object).

LINQ operations (i.e. the .OrderBy) returns a *query*.  It **does not** perform the operation on your object (i.e. `lst`).

You need to assign the *result* of that query back to your variable:

```
lst = lst.OrderBy(p => p).ToList();
```

in LINQ lingo.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] words = { "bac", "abc", "cab" };

var sortedWords = from w in words
                  orderby w
                  select w;

Console.WriteLine("The sorted list of words:");

foreach (var w in sortedWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine(w);
}
```