# How can I sort distinct vals in LINQ (C#)?

Tags: c#, linq, generic-list, distinct-values

I've got this LINQ to get the distinct values of a particular class member from a generic list:

```
var distinctDescriptions = itemsForMonthYearList.Select(x => x.ItemDescription).Distinct();
```

The generic list is defined this way:

```
List<ItemsForMonthYear> itemsForMonthYearList;
```

The class is:

```
public class ItemsForMonthYear
{
    public String ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public String monthYr { get; set; }
    public int TotalPackages { get; set; }
    public Decimal TotalPurchases { get; set; }
    public Decimal AveragePrice { get; set; }
    public Double PercentOfTotal { get; set; }
}
```

I thought this would work:

```
var distinctDescriptions = itemsForMonthYearList.Select(x => x.ItemDescription).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.ItemDescription);
```

...but it doesn't even compile:

> "*'string' does not contain a definition for 'ItemDescription' and no
>   extension method 'ItemDescription' accepting a first argument of type
>   'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)*"

How can I sort the distinct values alphabetically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you have already projected the property `ItemDescription` so it is `IEnumerable<String>` now, so you simply need to order by it's items:-

```
var distinctDescriptions = itemsForMonthYearList.Select(x => x.ItemDescription)
                                                .Distinct()
                                                .OrderBy(x => x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are projecting only one property of type `string`, so, the result is a `string` collection. Try this:

```
var distinctDescriptions = itemsForMonthYearList.Select(x => x.ItemDescription).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have already mentioned, your `Select` projects the property into collection of strings, and strings don't have an `ItemDescription` property, so you can't order by that.

Instead, you can follow the advice from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295971/sorting-a-list-with-orderby):

Convert the `Select` return collection to a List, then sort that.

```
var distinctDescriptions = itemsForMonthYearList.Select(x => x.ItemDescription).Distinct().ToList();
distinctDescriptions.Sort();
```

This will return a `List<string>` in sorted order.